# Two exact same stores, one with https + varnish and redis for page cache is slower than disk cache?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

PHP, code and server exactly the same.

Site 1:

- Varnish cache
- HTTPS + SSL termination with nginx
- redis for default cache
- redis for page cache (same instance)

  Average page time is 4281.0983896255

Site 2:

- Normal page cache
- No HTTPS
- No redis (file cache)

  Average page time is 2556.9653511047

I know that magento recommends the default cache be on a different redis instance than the one running the page cache.

Would that be the main reason or is it perhaps the Https causing the slow response.

Speed results conducted using [wfpc](https://github.com/quickshiftin/wfpc)

Comment: The SSL termination should in *no way* provide a slowdown of 2 seconds (more like 20ms). Are you sure the sitemaps are identical?

Comment: They are not identical, but are 95% the same. These results are from a random 10 requests. Perhaps I should test with weppagespeedtest.org

Comment: Better use a tool like [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) where manually specify the request target, number of requests and amount of concurrent requests

Comment: are you sure Varnish caches https requests??

Comment: Nginx handles the SSL, then sends request to varnish on port 80

Comment: I think I have quite the same problem, but https doesn't play important role. I found Varnish isn't properly dealing with Magento. Please share some insights if you have.